# Sum values of 2 vectors

Tags: c++, vector, std

Is there any implemented method in the C++ library which allows you to sum the values of two vectors (of the same size and type of course)? 

For example:

```
std::vector<int> a;//looks like this: 2,0,1,5,0
std::vector<int> b;//looks like this: 0,0,1,3,5
```

Now then adding their values together should look like this:

```
//2,0,2,8,5
```

The answer I'm expecting is either "No there isn't" or "yes" + method.

Comment: There's an overload of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) that operates on pairs of elements from two ranges.

Comment: btw, I've noticed some people thought it to be right to down-vote this question. Any specific reason for that? I'm at least quite certain I've followed all the rules regarding asking a question properly :|

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use [**`std::transform`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and [**`std::plus<int>()`**](http://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus)

```
std::vector<int> a;//looks like this: 2,0,1,5,0
std::vector<int> b;//looks like this: 0,0,1,3,5

// std::plus adds together its two arguments:
std::transform (a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), a.begin(), std::plus<int>());
// a = 2,0,2,8,5
```

This form of `std::transform` takes 5 arguments:

- Two first are input iterators to the initial and final positions of the first sequence.
- The third is an input iterator to the initial position of the second range.
- The fourth is an output iterator of the initial position of the range where the operation results are stored.
- The last argument is a binary function that accepts two elements as argument (one of each of the two sequences), and returns some result value convertible to the type pointed by OutputIterator.

Comment: Cheers, that's exactly what I was looking for:) Will accept that as the answer as soon as possible :p

Comment: I corrected arguments. Two first are input iterators to the initial and final positions of the first sequence. The third one the initial position of the second range. The Fourth one the initial position of the range where the operation results are stored. The last one the operation performed.

Comment: Ok, Python guy here, so bear with me please.. It's not possible to add vector (of the same length) with `+` sign? I would need to do some operator overloading?

Comment: @quapka No, you can't use `+` sign. I would recommend to create a function which implements the above. If you decided to overload the `+` operator, you should do it at global scope.

Comment: does this work when the vectors are of different size?