# sum up vectors in a matrix, element by element in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, sum, components

Is there a simple method in C++ that allows to sum up the vectors componing a matrix element by element? I mean, if I have the matrix `M[3][4]`, I want the `sum[3]` vector with this components:

```
sum[0]=M[0][0]+M[1][0]+M[2][0]
sum[1]=M[0][1]+M[1][1]+M[2][1]
sum[2]=M[0][2]+M[1][2]+M[2][2]
```

I find out that exists [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607912/sum-values-of-2-vectors) for two vectors, I would like to extend it to many vectors, in particular to the `std::vector<type>rows` componing the matrix `std::vector<vector<type> > M`, not knowing a-priori the dimomension of M.

Comment: Are you sure you want `sum[0]` to contain the sum the first **column**, not the first **row**?

Comment: totally sure. If my matrix is M{ {1,2,3},{4,5,6}} I want sum to be sum={5,7,9}.

Comment: I see. I think I'd then start by transposing the matrix and then doing the calculations on rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple method in C++ that allows to sum up the vectors componing a matrix element by element? I mean, if I have the matrix M[3][4], I want the sum[3] vector with this components:
>
> ```cpp
> sum[0]=M[0][0]+M[1][0]+M[2][0]
> sum[1]=M[0][1]+M[1][1]+M[2][1]
> sum[2]=M[0][2]+M[1][2]+M[2][2]
> ```

Unfortunately, there is no *simple method* in the C++ standard library for adding
a container's elements column-wise.

There is `std::accumulate()`, but naturally, it would add up the *row elements* together, not the column elements, but we can fix that by iterating through each column index inside the matrix and adding up the elements one by one:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>

// The below function assumes that all columns of your matrix have the same length
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> m_col_add(std::vector<std::vector<T>> const& mat) {
    std::vector<T> res;
    const auto column_size = mat[0].size();
    for (size_t x = 0; x < column_size; ++x)
        res.push_back(std::accumulate(mat.begin(), mat.end(), T{}, [x](T const& a, std::vector<T> const& row) {
            return a + row[x];
        }));
    return res;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12}
    };
    auto res = m_col_add(mat);
    for (auto const& elem : res)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

*Output*:

```
15 18 21 24
```

---

**Alternatively**, if you already know the sizes of the rows and columns during compile-time and are using C++17 or above, you can use [*fold expressions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) and [`std::index_sequence<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to add up the elements faster by compile-time expansion:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>

template <size_t Column, typename T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns, size_t ...Sizes>
T m_col_add_impl2(std::index_sequence<Sizes...>, std::array<std::array<T, Columns>, Rows> const& mat) {
    return (mat[Sizes][Column] + ...);
}

template <typename T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns, size_t ...Sizes>
std::array<T, Columns> m_col_add_impl1(std::index_sequence<Sizes...>, std::array<std::array<T, Columns>, Rows> const& mat) {
    std::array<T, Columns> sum;
    ((sum[Sizes] = m_col_add_impl2<Sizes>(std::make_index_sequence<Rows>(), mat)), ...);
    return sum;
}

template <typename T, size_t Rows, size_t Columns>
std::array<T, Columns> m_col_add(std::array<std::array<T, Columns>, Rows> const& mat) {
    return m_col_add_impl1(std::make_index_sequence<Columns>(), mat);
}

int main() {
    std::array mat {
        std::array {1, 2, 3, 4},
        std::array {5, 6, 7, 8},
        std::array {9, 10, 11, 12}
    };
    auto res = m_col_add(mat);
    for (auto const& elem : res)
    std::cout << elem << " ";
}
```

*Output*:

```
15 18 21 24
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define `operator+=` for vectors which allows you to define a generalized `Sum` function that receives begin and end operators of a range to sum that works for iterators with any value type that works with the `+=` operator like primitive types or (possibly nested) vectors of types that provide a `+=` operator:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T>& operator+=(std::vector<T>& lhs, std::vector<T> const& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.empty())
    {
        lhs = rhs; // first summand; 0 + x = x 
    }
    else
    {    
        for (size_t i = 0; i < lhs.size(); ++i)
        {
            lhs[i] += rhs.at(i); // component-wise add
        }
    }
    return lhs;
}

// sum up elements in a given range
template<typename IteratorType>
typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type Sum(IteratorType summandBegin, IteratorType summandEnd)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorType>::value_type sum {}; // 0 or object created with default constructor depending on the type
    while (summandBegin != summandEnd)
    {
        sum += *summandBegin;
        ++summandBegin;
    }
    return sum;
}

// sums the first count elements of a vector
template<typename T>
T PartialSum(std::vector<T> const& vec, size_t count)
{
    assert(vec.size() >= count);
    return Sum(vec.begin(), vec.begin() + count);
}

// logic for displaying
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
    s << '{';
    for (auto& val : vec)
    {
        s << val << ", ";
    }
    s << '}';
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> matrix { {{1, 2},{ 3, 4},{ 5, 6}},{{7, 8},{ 9, 10},{11, 12}},{{13, 14},{ 15, 16},{ 17, 18}}};

    auto partialSum = PartialSum(matrix, 2);

    std::cout << matrix << '\n' << partialSum << '\n';

    std::cout << "\nSomething extra:\n";
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> m2 = {{"Hell" , "Wo"} , {"o ", "rld!"}, {"foo", "bar"}};
    auto message = PartialSum(m2, 2);
    for (auto& msg : message)
    {
        std::cout << msg;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```