# How do I get weighted sum of 2 vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I saw the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28607912/sum-values-of-2-vectors) to sum 2 vectors. I wanted to do a weighted sum.

```
std::vector<int> a;//looks like this: 2,0,1,5,0
std::vector<int> b;//looks like this: 0,0,1,3,5
```

I want to do `a * 0.25 + b * 0.75` and store in some vector.
I saw this function `std::transform` but wanted to know how do I write a custom operation for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Version 1**: Using `std::transform` and a lambda

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> a{2,0,1,5,0};
    std::vector<int> b{0,0,1,3,5};

    //create a new vector that will contain the resulting values
    std::vector<double> result(a.size());
    std::transform (a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), [](int p, int q) -> double { return (p * 0.25) + (q * 0.75); });
    for(double elem: result)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 2**: Using a free function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
double weightedSum(int p, int q)
{
    return (p * 0.25) + (q * 0.75);
}
int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> a{2,0,1,5,0};
    std::vector<int> b{0,0,1,3,5};

    //create a new vector that will contain the resulting values
    std::vector<double> result(a.size());
    std::transform (a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), weightedSum);
    for(double elem: result)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Version 3**: Passing the weights as arguments using `std::bind`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include <functional>

using namespace std::placeholders;
double weightedSum(int p, int q, double weightA, double weightB)
{
    return (p * weightA) + (q * weightB);
}
int main()
{ 
    std::vector<int> a{2,0,1,5,0};
    std::vector<int> b{0,0,1,3,5};

    //create a new vector that will contain the resulting values
    std::vector<double> result(a.size());
    std::transform (a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), result.begin(), std::bind(weightedSum, _1, _2, 0.25, 0.75));
    for(double elem: result)
    {
        std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're answer was posted just before mine so I'm going to delete it to reduce clutter.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Lets say with free function, can I pass an argument (like the value of weight) to the weighted sum function as well via std::transform?

Comment: @HarshSharma Yes that(passing the weights value as argument) is possible as i have added at the end of my answer(**version 3**). Check version 3 out.